# Difference between process and thread

Tags: java, multithreading, process

I was asked a question during interview today. First they asked how to provide Synchronization
between thread. Then they asked how to provide Synchronization between process, because I told them, the variable inside each process can not be shared with other process, so they asked me to explain how two process can communicate with each other and how to provide Synchronization 
between them, and where to declare the shared variable? Now the interview finished, but I want to know the answer, can anyone explain me?Thank you.

Comment: A shared wait, such as a named Mutex or Semaphore, would would to synchronize calls accross a process.

Comment: True inter-process communication is highly platform dependent.  Usually you dodge that by communicating over network sockets between processes.  I would personally be tempted to give the somewhat glib but highly correct from a business aspect answer "Buy a terracotta license." :)

Comment: ok, for example, Mutex or Semaphore, so this means we need a semaphore variable, so these processes can access it and check it. so where to declare it? inside each process?

Comment: careful: cross-process mutex and semaphores are not supported directly in Java. The Java `Semaphore` class is a pure in-process tool. More generally, most operating systems provide a semaphore mechanism for cross-process synchronization, but that's not easily accessible from Java code.

Comment: I think an important point of this question is: was the question about Java in particular or about more general mechanisms?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the interviewer(s) may not be using the proper terminology.  A process runs in its own space, and has been mentioned in separate answers, you have to use OS-specific mechanisms to communicate between process.  This is called IPC for Inter-Process Communication.

Using sockets is a common practice, but can be grossly inefficient, depending on your application.  But if working with pure Java, this may be the only option since sockets are universally supported.

Shared memory is another technique, but that is OS-specific and requires OS-specific calls.  You would have to use something like JNI for a Java application to access shared memory services.  Shared memory access is not synchronized, so you will likely have to use semaphors to synchronize access among multiple processes.

Unix-like systems provide multiple IPC mechansims, and which one to use depends on the nature of your application.  Shared memory can be a limited resource, so it may not be the best method.  Googling on this topics provides numerous hits providing useful information on the technical details.

Answer (score 3):

A process is a collection of virtual memory space, code, data, and system resources. A thread is code that is to be serially executed within a process. A processor executes threads, not processes, so each application has at least one process, and a process always has at least one thread of execution, known as the primary thread. A process can have multiple threads in addition to the primary thread. Prior to the introduction of multiple threads of execution, applications were all designed to run on a single thread of execution.

When a thread begins to execute, it continues until it is killed or until it is interrupted by a thread with higher priority (by a user action or the kernel's thread scheduler). Each thread can run separate sections of code, or multiple threads can execute the same section of code. Threads executing the same block of code maintain separate stacks. Each thread in a process shares that process's global variables and resources.

Answer (score 2):

To communicate between two processes I suppose you can use a ServerSocket and Socket to manage process synchronization.  You would bind to a specific port (acquire lock) and if a process already is bound you can connect to the socket (block) and wait until the server socket is closed.

```
private static int KNOWN_PORT = 11000;//arbitrary valid port
private ServerSocket socket;
public void acquireProcessLock(){
   socket = new ServetSocket(KNOWN_PORT);
   INetAddress localhostInetAddres = ...
   try{
      socket.bind(localhostInetAddres );
   }catch(IOException failed){
      try{
       Socket socket = new Socket(localhostInetAddres ,KNOWN_PORT);
       socket.getInputStream().read();//block
      }catch(IOException ex){ acquireProcessLock(); } //other process invoked releaseProcessLock()
   }
}
public void releaseProcessLock(){
  socket.close();
}
```

Not sure if this is the actual best means of doing it but I think its worth considering.

Comment: I also answered them using Socket to communicate with each other. But they do not satisfied.And they repeat the question again and again, so any other thought?

Comment: Beware, however, that OS-es sometimes forbid second bind to the same port from different process or user.

Comment: @Piotr thank you for that. I  put it together a bit quickly but I am sure there would be OS specific issues to go over.  @ratzip I am assuming you mean two separate JVMs running on two separate processes.  If thats the case, they would share the same memory (obviously virtual) but neither has pointers to one anothers memory.  So you cannot synchronize on objects under separate processes.  Were they looking for something specific when they said you cannot use Sockets and IO?

Comment: They asked how two processes can communicate with each other and be synchronized. This is the question. I through maybe two processes can be Synchronized the way thread does. So I told them one process wait for another put value to a common variable, and then it can fetch it.so they asked where to declare the common variable since the variable can not be shared by processes?

Comment: They may have been looking for something really specific, but generally speaking.  Two process cannot synchronize on a shared piece of memory you would see in java code like synchronize(myObject){ ... }.  Two processes don't know about eachothers heap and in turn reference to virtual memory.

Answer (score 1):

Synchronization is for threads only it wont work for processes in Java. There is no utility in them working across processes, since the processes do not share any state that would need to be synchronized. A variable in one process will not have the same data as a variable in the other process

Comment: yes, I understand your answer, the processes do not share any state,but I wonder if two processes will access the same shared memory? in this case, shall we consider Synchronization?

Answer (score 1):

From a system point of view, a thread is defined by his "**state**" and the "**instruction pointer**".

The instruction pointer (**eip**) contains the address of the next instruction to be executed.

A thread "**state**" can be : the **registers** (eax, ebx,etc), the **signals**, the **open files**, the **code**, the **stack**, the **data** managed by this thread (variables, arrays, etc) and also the **heap**.

A **process** is a group of threads that share a part of their "**state**": it might be the **code**, the **data**, the **heap**. 
Hope i answer your question ;)

EDIT: 
The processes can communicate via the IPCs (Inter process communications). There are 3 mecanisms : **shared memory**, **message queue**. Synchronization between processes can me made with the **Semaphors**

Threads synchronization can me made with **mutexes** (**pthread_mutex_lock, pthread_mutex_unlock, etc**)

Comment: yes, thank you. But my question is how two processes can communicate with each other? And does the situation exist: two processes access a share memory? if so, how to provide Synchronization?

Comment: I explain them the producer and consumer problem, using lock, Semaphore,but they asked how to provide Synchronization between processes, I answered them declare a common variable, so they asked since the variable in each process can not be shared with others, so where to declare the common variable?

Comment: note that your register names (eip, eax, ebx) are system-dependent (x86 in your case), while the rest of your answer is pretty universal.

Comment: Yeah I know, but it was for an example purpose only.

Comment: @ratzip  one thing I have done before is to implement sychronization between SMPs in FPGA. I think this is very similiar to your problem. The point is to use a  'hardware' mutex which can be accessed by both processors. There is a hardare mutex IP core that can be created in SOPC builder.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Terracotta Cluster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terracotta_Cluster) or Terracotta's [DSO Clustering](http://www.terracotta.org/confluence/display/docs/How+DSO+Clustering+Works) documentation to see how this issue can be solved (bytecode manipulation, maintaince the semantics of Java Language Specification on putfield/getfield-level etc.)

Answer (score 0):

the most simplest answer is process means a program under execution and a program is nothing but collection of functions.
where thread is the part of the proccess because all the threads are functions.
in other way we can say that a process may have multiple threads.
always OS allocates the memory for a process and that memory is disributed among the threads of that process.OS does not allocates memory for threads.

Answer (score 0):

In one sentence processes are designed more independently than threads are.
Their major differences can be described at memory level. Different **processes** share nothing among each other, from register, stock memory to heap memory, which make them safe on their own tracks. However, normally **threads** are designed to share a common heap memory, which provides a more closely connected way for multiple processes computing task. Creating a more efficient way to take up computation resources.

E.g. If I compute with 3 processes, I have to let them each finish their jobs and wait for their results in a system level, at the mean time, registers and stack memory are always taken up. However, if I do it with 3 threads, then if thread 2 luckily finish its job earlier, because the result it computed had already been stored to the common heap memory pool, we can simply kill it without waiting for others to deliver their results, and this released resources of registers and stock memory can be used on other purposes.

Answer (score -1):

Process:

- A process is nothing but a program under  execution.
- Each process have its own memory address space.
- Process are used for heavyweight tasks i.e. is basically execution of applications.
- Cost of communication between process is high.
- Switching from one process to another require some time for saving and loading registers, memory maps etc.
- Process is operating system approach.

Threads:

- A thread is light weight sub-process.
- Thread share the same address space.
- Cost of communication between the thread is low.

Note: At least one process is required for each thread.

Answer (score -2):

I suppose the processes can communicate through a third-party : a file or a database...